# Google auth credentials error. Requires a JSON file, provided a TOML file

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, streamlit, toml

I am trying to host a project with google cloud vision in streamlit cloud. Streamlit requires the google auth credentials file to be .toml while google cloud requires it to be in .json.

[image: 1]

```py
def detect_document(path):
    cred =  ".streamlit/secrets.toml"
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = cred

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.Image(content=content)
```

I cannot put my GCP credentials in github since it is a security risk. Any work around or suggestion for this issue.

Comment: Read this [guide](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/gcs), it might help in your case.

Comment: What is `secrets.toml`? You should be specifying a Google Cloud Service Account JSON key file.

Answer (score 0):

As [@ferdy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842042/google-auth-credentials-error-requires-a-json-file-provided-a-toml-file#comment132081328_74842042) suggested, go read the [Connect Streamlit to Google Cloud Storage](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/gcs).

The steps you are probably missing:

- [Copy your app secrets to the cloud](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/gcs#copy-your-app-secrets-to-the-cloud).

  > As the `secrets.toml` file above is not committed to GitHub, you need to
  > pass its content to your deployed app (on Streamlit Community Cloud)
  > separately.

  This avoids storing them on GitHub as you stated you don't want to do (and rightfully so).
- [Use the newly stored credentials](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/gcs#write-your-streamlit-app):

  ```py
  import streamlit as st
  from google.oauth2 import service_account
  from google.cloud import storage

  # Create API client.
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
      st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]
  )
  client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
  ```